Is it possible to annotate the type of a Svelte component?
I have several Svelte components, for example: Melon.svelte, Cherry.svelte, Phone.svelte. In a parent component, FruitBox.svelte, using <svelte:component>, I want to be able to dynamically render only fruit components, but not others.
Is there a way to annotate my components in some way, that would allow to semantically differentiate them?
<!-- FruitBox.svelte --> 
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import Cherry from './Cherry.svelte';
  import Melon from './Melon.svelte';
  import Phone from './Phone.svelte';

  // can this be more specific than "any"?
  let fruitType: any;

  onMount(() => { fruitType = pickRandomFruit(); })

  function pickRandomFruit(): any // I want type annotation / compile time check here
  {
    // return Phone; <-- this would also work, but I want to limit that
    return (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? Melon : Cherry; 
  }
</script>

<svelte:component this={fruitType} /> 

I understand Svelte doesn't have inheritance -- however, I don't need to share functionality or elements between components, but rather simple type annotation. Can this be achieved?

Check if ComponentType fixes your problem.

@PeppeL-G Thank you for the tip, that's pretty much what I needed! This helps a lot with export let props, and covers almost all needs. I haven't found a way to express that a component needs to implement a dispatcher. For example if I want all fruit components to have a dispatcher of a specific name and return type, like on:juice={j => drink(j)}, where j: FruitJuice. I assume this is because a dispatcher made with Svelte's createEventDispatcher is an internal prop, not an export. But can live without that. If you want to write that link in an answer, I can mark as correct.

Update on previous comment: there is a way to annotate events also, in the SvelteComponent generic type, you can specify three type variables: props, events, and slots. See answer for details.

As suggested in the comment by @Peppe L-G, using Svelte's ComponentType type and SvelteComponent class can help with this:
<!-- FruitBox.svelte --> 
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import Cherry from './Cherry.svelte';
  import Melon from './Melon.svelte';
  import Phone from './Phone.svelte';

  import { type ComponentType, SvelteComponent } from "svelte";

  export type FruitComponent = ComponentType<SvelteComponent<
    { hasSeeds: boolean, weightGrams: number }, // Props
    { juice: CustomEvent<FruitJuice> } // Events
  >>;

  let fruit: FruitComponent;

  onMount(() => { fruit = pickRandomFruit(); })

  function pickRandomFruit(): FruitComponent {
    return (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? Melon : Cherry; 
  }

  function drink(juice: FruitJuice) {
    console.log("tasty");
  }
</script>

<svelte:component 
  this={fruit}
  hasSeeds={true}
  weightGrams={100} 
  on:juice={(j) => drink(j)}
/> 

This will require that both Melon.svelte and Cherry.svelte (and any other component constructor returned by pickRandomFruit()) to have the following props:
<script lang="ts">
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

  export let hasSeeds: boolean;
  export let weightGrams: number;

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher<{juice: FruitJuice}>();
</script>

, and won't allow the the function to return a Phone constructor, or any other constructor of a component that doesn't have those props.
